# unify two columns and create a column to indicate the previous unified columns name

Tags: r

I would like to unify two columns with values in one and create another column which indicates the columns names of the two columns from the beginning.

```
structure(list(moda = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BS1", "HW1", "PG"), class = "factor"), 
t0 = c(1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 1.2, 1, 2.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 2, 
1.8, 2.3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2.1, 1.8, 1.3, 2, 1.5, 2, 
3.5, 1.5, 1.7), t14 = c(1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 1.2, 1, 2.4, 
1.3, 1.4, 5, 7, 2.5, 6.5, 5.4, 5, 6, 5.7, 7, 3.5, 4.7, 4.5, 
5.9, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
structure(list(moda = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "HW1",       class = "factor"), 
time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("t0", 
"t14"), class = "factor"), unified = c(1.7, 2, 1.8, 5, 7, 
2.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

So the idea is to get at the end t0 and t14 column unified into a new column. And to get a another column which indicates t0 or t14 for each value of the unified column. 
Edit the second structure illustrate an short example of the output desired.

Comment: how do you have only 6 rows in your output? What is the basis of their selection? Do you need something like `stack(df[-1])` ?

Comment: No sorry, it was just to illustrate how the structure of the df would be, but i would like to have all the rows and not just few of them like i did to illustrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gather` here

```
library(tidyr)
dflong <-  gather(df1, time, unified, t0:t14)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Is it possible from dflong to come back to df1?

Comment: @Simon You can do a `spread`, `library(dplyr);dflong %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(rn =row_number()) %>% spread(time, unified, fill = 0) %>% select(-rn) -> df2;
all.equal(df2, df1)#
[1] TRUE`